# What are the common nutritional deficiencies in western countries related to reduced mental performance?

Tags: neuroscience, performance, mental-exhaustion

What are the common nutritional deficiencies in western countries related to reduced mental performance ? I've heard about omega 3, folid acid, and vitamin D deficiencies, the last two are now reduced due to food suplementation in some countries.

Comment: This is an interesting question, but "mental performance" is much too broad and vague a measure to be answered meaningfully, at least for me. Recommendations:
1) Add some background literature to provide context on what kind of performance you're thinking of.
2) Restrict the scope of the question to a (few) specific measure(s). Something like "What is the association between common nutritional deficiencies and working memory?" would be more amenable to answering.

Comment: @Christian Hummeluhr yes, but I've used that world because i wanted to obtain **any** answer to have start point for future questions/reaserch

Comment: I found that a buildup of homocysteine in the brain can lead to negative cognitive effects. It is metabolized using vitamins B6 and B12.

Comment: I heard about selenium deficiency in some countries have very low levels of it in soil, but I'm not sure, how it influence mental functions